# Date formatting and how to print the highest number that occured and on what date

Tags: python, pandas

In the following data, I want to get the highest number of `Swings` that occurred and also on what `Date`. I can already get the highest number of Swings that occurred but not sure how to get the corresponding Date:

```
data = [
    {"Date": "01/06/2020",  "Swings": 350},
    {"Date": "02/06/2020",  "Swings": 370},
]
df = pd.DataFrame(data)

max_swings = max(df['Swings'])

print ("The max number of swings in one day was: " + str(max_swings))
```

(Note: I use DD/MM/YYYY date format)

Comment: I don't understand what you mean by *"What is the best format to put the date in - is what I have optimal?"* Do you mean *"so that pandas will parse it by default and not swap days with months"* or *"alphanumeric sort will also put the date in chronological order"* or *"most intuitive to people from country X?"* What are your criteria? for what operation? There is no one single 'optimal' date format.

Comment: doing `max_swings = np.max(df['Swings'.values])` will be significantly faster for large dataframes.

Comment: @Aramakus: `max_swings = df['Swings'].max()` is better pandas idiom, also clearer and shorter.

Comment: Thanks so now I'm looking for what date that max swing occured on?

Comment: i guess you can start with `df[df['Swings'].eq(df['Swings'].max())]` to get the rows with maximum swings then parse the date and swing column

Comment: I'm editing out the subjective question *"Is DD/MM/YYYY format optimal?"* to keep this on-topic and answerable, per [SO rules](https://stackoverflow.com/help/dont-ask)

Answer (score 2):

Usually we convert dates to `datetime`.

```
df['Date'] = pd.to_datetime(df['Date']) # convert to datetime

df.iloc[df['Swings'].idxmax()] # this gives you the row with the highest swings
```

The `df['Swings'].idxmax()` gives you the index of the first occurence where the maximum value of Swings is. Then you can slice the dataframe on that row with the `.iloc[]`

Comment: Just incase you have duplicate max values in Swings column, you can compare `series.max()` and then do a boolean indexing but not sure how OP wants to go about it then, probably a `agg(','.join)`

Comment: Works perfectly, how do I convert the date format into UK - dd/mm/yy?

Comment: you can do `df['Date'] = pd.to_datetime(df['Date']).dt.strftime('%d/%m/%y')` but this pandas series is of type string not datetime.

Answer (score 0):

#### 1) `idxmax()` : will find first row with maximum

This is a one-liner with the pandas function [`idxmax()`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.idxmax.html), which gives you the (integer) index of the row containing the maximum of your column of interest:

```
df.iloc[ df['Swings'].idxmax() ]

Date      02/06/2020
Swings           370
```

#### 2) Logical indexing: will find all rows with maximum

Note  if there were multiple rows with maxima, `idxmax()` will only find the first row, so you'd need to use logical indexing:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({"Date": ['01/06/2020','02/06/2020','01/06/2020','05/06/2020'], "Swings": [350,370,370,300]})

         Date  Swings
0  01/06/2020     350
1  02/06/2020     370
2  01/06/2020     370
3  05/06/2020     300

>>> df[df['Swings'] == df['Swings'].max()]

         Date  Swings
1  02/06/2020     370
2  01/06/2020     370
```